# How to disable bootstrap collapse when clicking on the particular element inside header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've the following code to collapse and open the content.

```
<h4 class="cartToggleTags collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cotent1">
  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Header1
</h4>
<div id="cotent1" class="collapse in">
  Content 1
</div>
```

How to disable collapse or open funcntionality when clicking on the edit icon `<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent accordion from toggling when button in header is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469602/how-to-prevent-accordion-from-toggling-when-button-in-header-is-clicked)

Answer (score 3):

You could simply stop the event propagation, eg

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle=collapse] .fa', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3MEEP/